# Bot post works in postman but not in flutter

Tags: flutter, request, postman, bots

Hello guys im currently in a project that is using a bot that gives data about a place when you send in the message. The problem is related to a new feature. When i write to the bot something like *"tell me something curious about bar cordano"* it gives me some information about it and if you resend a message just like "*tell me something curious*" (this is the new feature) it also gives me some information about the place that i've wrote previously.

Everything works fine when i do the request in postman but the thing is that when i try to do it in flutter it doesnt recognize the place in the second message i just gives me an error message "*there is no information about this place*". I just ask this because maybe there is something that im missing in my request ,hope you can help me.

My Postman request :[image]

[image]

My flutter request format (already used flutter http and it didn't work)

```
    final String userId = UserPreferences().getUserId().toString();

    final url =
        Uri.parse('URL');

    final String userToken = UserPreferences().getToken();

    String dateFormat =
        "${DateTime.now().toLocal().year.toString()}-${DateTime.now().toLocal().month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${DateTime.now().toLocal().day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}";

    var body = {
      "text": message,
      "user": int.parse(userId),
      "date": dateFormat,
      "url": "www.test14.com",
      "is_user": true
    };

    var resp = await Dio().post(url.toString(),
        data: body,
        options: Options(headers: <String, String>{
          'Authorization': userToken,
          'Cookie': 'session=$userToken',
          'Connection': 'keep-alive',
          'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=5,max=100',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        }));
```

Comment: I might be missing something here but you're showing us the headers for the request in Postman but showing us how you're constructing the body of the HTTP request? Those are two disparate pieces of information.

Comment: @NicoSpencer you are right i already updated it, thanks. Now is all the request